# Link foreign key to unique element

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a list with some promo codes. I have another list with items which I want to link with the promo codes.
The constraint which is important to me is that every item should be linked to exactly one promo code. It is easy to generate the promo code in the item. My problem is that the list of promo codes is created before the items - so I don't know if a promo code is assigned before trying to save the modifications in which case it may throw exception. How can I solve my issues with MySQL?

Comment: You have pool of pre-generated promo codes. Then you're getting your items. So what's the problem to assign codes to items? Just do that one-by-one and write the corresponding FK value to items table.

Comment: If there are 2 requests I may possibly assign the same FK twice

Comment: Then check it. I can't see the problem for now

Comment: Maybe there is some traditional way that I don't know. I thought of trying to assign unique fk until I succeed or may be some kind of AUTO_INCREMENT counter which to tell me which exactly promo code to use. Generally speaking how to do this - assign promo code to item with the given constraint

Comment: Create unique index. Then use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` syntax

Comment: Are you getting problem at the time of creating constraint or after it inserting records.

Comment: @AlmaDo this seems like the thing I need. I am searching for examples now. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ZafarMalik I don't know how to do it properly. It is a problem in theory, I haven't written anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

step1: Your promocode table should have atleast 2 columns promo_id, promocode.

Step2: Your item table should have a column promo_id which contains promo_id from promocode table.

Step3: create a foreign key based on promo_id (item table as child table and promocode table as master table)

Note: It will give error if there is any promo_id exists in item table and not exist in promocode table, in this case you need to either first insert that promocode in promocode table or need to delete from item table.

Step4: create unique index on promocode column in promocode table.

Note: If there is any duplicate promocode then it will not allow so first make unique.

Step5: create combined unique index on (item_id, promo_id) columns in item table.

Note: If there is any duplicate record based on these 2 columns then it will not allow so first make unique.

Now you can proceed as you want.

If it does not full fill your requirement then please share more information.